# why can't I run CMD for command like this:

Tags: scripting, cmd

for /f %%i in ('someprogram %1 2>&1 | find /c "some string"') do ...

it says

2>&1 was unexpected at this time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to escape special characters within the `for` command:

```
for /f %%i in ('someprogram %1 2^>^&1 ^| find /c "some string"') do ...
```

`cmd`'s parser is not the most robust one; this is unfortunately necessary.